# ValueError when adding a layer to other data frames

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to write a script that adds the parks layer from the Parks data frame in Austin_TX.mxd to the other two data frames in the same map document.

This is the script I have but i keep getting a ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:/Python/Homework8/Exercise10/Austin_TX.mxd")
dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Parks")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("parks.lyr")
for df in dfList:
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
mxd.saveACopy(r"E:/Python/Homework8/Exercise10/Austin_TX.mxd")
del mxd, addLayer
```

the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/Homework8/Exercise10/Results/HW8_Ch1.py", line 4, in <module>
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("parks.lyr")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 402, in __init__
    super(LayerMixin, self).__init__(lyrfile)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 47, in __init__
    for arg in args))
ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
```

Comment: If it is ArcPy I think you will always be better researching/asking at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

[A Layer object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) is intended to refer to a layer file on disk, not a layer within a map document (MXD).

To work with a layer within your MXD, use [ListDataFrames](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listdataframes.htm) and [ListLayers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm).

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Parks")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "parks.lyr", df)[0]
```